# Connect a third-party application (MS Excel) with SAP R/3

Tags: excel, vba, saprfc, sap-basis

I'm working out a solution for communicate MS Excel (a VBA macro) with SAP. Sometimes is too hard to reach SAP support people at any company you are working for, so it is better to figure out your own solution.

About that reason, I started with the basic: "connect my own User profile with SAP R/3". Doing some Google research, I found a good [paper](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-10447) with the connectivity and here is the key part of the code:

```
Dim objBAPIControl As Object 'Function Control (Collective object)
Dim sapConnection As Object 'Connection object
Set objBAPIControl = CreateObject("SAP.Functions")
Set sapConnection = objBAPIControl.Connection

sapConnection.client = "32"
sapConnection.user = "myUser"
sapConnection.Language = "EN"
sapConnection.hostname = "qwerty.example.com"
sapConnection.Password = "myPass"
```

(and more user profile values........)

Later on, I did the second step which was reading some table (in this case, the Users Table)

```
If sapConnection.logon(1, True) <> True Then
MsgBox "No connection to R/3!"
Exit Sub 'End program
End If
Set objUserList = objBAPIControl.Add("BAPI_USER_GETLIST")
Set objUserDetail = objBAPIControl.Add("BAPI_USER_GET_DETAIL")

returnFunc = objUserList.Call
If returnFunc = True Then
Dim objTable As Object
Set objTable = objUserList.Tables("USERLIST")
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "User count :" & objTable.RowCount
```

But now, here is my question: How to run some transaction (LM02, LS26, LX03, or etc) fired from VBA ?

### Thank you guys!

PS. I'm using MS Office 2007 and Windows 7.

--
EDITED:

Hey I change the way I was attacking the challenge ( I will let the OP above for helping some other guy)

This must be add to the first

```
Dim RfcCallTransaction As Object
Dim Messages As Object
Dim BdcTable As Object
```

The connection to SAP is the same, but once you're logged in:

```
If objBAPIControl.Connection.Logon(0, False) <> True Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Set RfcCallTransaction = objBAPIControl.Add("RFC_CALL_TRANSACTION_USING")
```

[here](http://www.se80.co.uk/sapfms/r/rfc_/rfc_call_transaction_using.htm) you can find the "new" arguments for the `RFC_CALL_TRANSACTION` old function.

```
    RfcCallTransaction.exports("tcode") = "SE16"
    RfcCallTransaction.exports("mode") = "N"
Set BdcTable = RfcCallTransaction.Tables("bt_data")
```

Until this part I'm sure of three things:

1) It does connect to SAP R/3

2) It Runs the "SE16" transaction

3) It could receive the Batch input from a BdcTable

The missing part is, how to "format" the BdcTable (I think it must be in ABAP language) to upload the exact Data (table) that I want to be run at SE16.

EDITED:
I found an example of the "formatting" table I'm looking for:

```
add_bdcdata BdcTable, "SAPLSETB", "230", "X", "", ""
add_bdcdata BdcTable, "", "", "", "BDC_CURSOR", "DATABROWSE-TABLENAME"
add_bdcdata BdcTable, "", "", "", "BDC_OKCODE", "=ANZE"
add_bdcdata BdcTable, "", "", "", "DATABROWSE-TABLENAME", "KNA1"
add_bdcdata BdcTable, "/1BCDWB/DBKNA1", "1000", "X", "", ""
add_bdcdata BdcTable, "", "", "", "BDC_CURSOR", "MAX_SEL"
add_bdcdata BdcTable, "", "", "", "BDC_OKCODE", "=ONLI"
add_bdcdata BdcTable, "", "", "", "LIST_BRE", "250"
add_bdcdata BdcTable, "", "", "", "MAX_SEL", "5"
add_bdcdata BdcTable, "SAPMSSY0", "120", "X", "", ""
add_bdcdata BdcTable, "", "", "", "BDC_CURSOR", "01/02/2012"
add_bdcdata BdcTable, "", "", "", "BDC_OKCODE", "=%EX"
add_bdcdata BdcTable, "/1BCDWB/DBKNA1", "1000", "X", "", ""
add_bdcdata BdcTable, "", "", "", "BDC_OKCODE", "/EE"
add_bdcdata BdcTable, "", "", "", "BDC_CURSOR", "I1-LOW"
add_bdcdata BdcTable, "SAPLSETB", "230", "X", "", ""
add_bdcdata BdcTable, "", "", "", "BDC_OKCODE", "/EBACK"
add_bdcdata BdcTable, "", "", "", "BDC_CURSOR", "DATABROWSE-TABLENAME"
```

The above code still being part of the VBA macro. But I don't know what do all those fills mean.

After this task is complete, the second challenge is to save the data automatically into a MS Excel sheet.

(Could you tell me if the all editing thing is working or should I just paste the new code and erase the history?)

EDITED:
I asked the same question as a summary in SCN platform. You can review it [here](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3236236).

EDITED:
My objective in this challenge is to run a transaction ( the TCODE I'm looking for is LM02, a bin to bin transaction for warehouse) via a VBA Macro, upload some date extracted from a MS Excel file and Execute the transaction.

--
last edit:
It seems like this task can't be done without the help of SAP IT support.
19/sep/12 | still researching about this topic. 25/09/12 |
02/OCT/12 --> I will try [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) for logging, run a basic Tcode and display the report. I'd Comment my results after I double checked it.

Answer (score 2):

Note: This is an alternative suggestion to @fabiopagoti's answer, a completely different approach.

If - as you suggested in another comment - you want to import data into R/3 applications, you'd better not try to bypass the company IT. Instead, you could try to talk to them and get access to the [Legacy System Migration Workbench](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/ad/2d54a41d7011d2b42e006094b944c8/frameset.htm) (LSMW). This is a powerful toolkit that allows you to record dialog steps (under certain conditions), import some data (for example from CSV files) and then combine the recording and the data to "replay" the same steps with different data - all using standard functions and without bypassing any security checks.

Comment: they're so hard to reach (may be because in our manufacture company the IT SAP support is physically in another country), but thank you for the advise. And you are correct, I'm looking for importing some information automatically from Excel to R/3 app.

Comment: @fabiopagoti You're not being constructive - do you always attribute the failures of the internal organization running the ERP software to the software itself?

Comment: @vwegert I'll delete my comment. However I was joking. As the faq says, "bring your sense of humor" - I tried to do it. Sorry if I failed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let me quote the best answer that I got. I'm pasting it here because I think somebody else will have the same question that I did.

> The step one is to understand if there' s a RFC or BAPI for your
>   transaction, but you don't have the permission for ABAP transactions,
>   so I don't know how you can find out it.
>
> Theorically you can try to looking for it in WEB or in SAP
>   documentation, but then (if it exists) you need to check the interface
>   where the the import/export parameters are defined.....so you should
>   have the authorization for SE37.
>
> The next step depends on if you can or can't find out a RFC function
>   for LM02:
>
> if there's a function, you need to understand how to run it
>
> if there isn't a function. you need to understand if you or an abaper
>   can develop a custom one.
>
> Max

Thank you for your research effort.

Comment: Credit: https://answers.sap.com/comments/9540682/view.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry my friend but you won't get much further than this.

What you are doing in your code is calling a BAPI (basically a RFC enable function). In other words, SAP provide standard functions which call be called from different systems. You can think this as an old fashioned API. It's also possible to create custom BAPIs, but in practice almost nobody does this.

The good news is that usually, I said usually BAPIs brings the same functionality of standard transactions. So in theory what you can do via transaction code you can do via BAPI call.

BAPI relation with transaction codes is not one to one. For example, you may use a single transaction which enables you inserting, searching, deleting and editing a particular kind of document but to achieve this using BAPI calls you will need many of them (one to create a document, one to delete, one to retrieve etc).

There's a transaction called "BAPI" (maybe the only tx code with a decent name) which contains all BAPIs in the system, its parameters and (some poor) documentation.

Comment: thank you for the advise. Another thing, is it possible to "load" some data from Excel to SAP without the help of SAP IT support and ABAP coding ?

Comment: That's true @vwegert. I forgot that one.

Comment: @fabiopagoti Set RfcCallTransaction = Functions.Add("RFC_CALL_TRANSACTION") still working or is now obsolete ?

Comment: @BrOSs I honestly have no idea. I have never used this RFC. Anyway it's important to remember that this is not a BAPI. Every BAPI is an RFC but not every RFC is a BAPI. Although I have no access to a SAP system now I bet there's just a single CALL TRANSACTION inside this function. I don't know also what would be its result and how a different system can use it.

Comment: @fabiopagoti The "new" function module now is ['RFC_CALL_TRANSACTION_USING'](http://www.se80.co.uk/sapfms/r/rfc_/rfc_call_transaction_using.htm) I will edit my question with this code update later.

Comment: @fabiopagoti hey man, how do you know that this RFC (RFC_CALL_TRANSACTION_USING) is not a BAPI ? I kept in mind you comment. thanks!

Comment: @BrOSs as far I know (I read this on the official C_TAW12_70 book from SAP Press) all BAPIs:
1) are RFC
2) begin with 'BAPI'
3) have a 'BAPIRETURN' returning parameter
4) handle business objects

Without checking BAPI txcode I assumed RFC_CALL_TRANSACTION_USING is not a BAPI as it violates #2 and #4 (and probably #3).